# Excel VBA: Google map API - one post code compared to many

Tags: excel, vba, api

I am trying to do an Excel VBA: Google map API that returns distance and time but I cannot seem to get it to work? The code does not seem to run which to me would mean it is not picking any postcodes up.

```
Sub main()

    Dim a, b, i, Str As String
    Dim lineS As Variant
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("WinHttpRequest.5.1")
        a = CStr(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C2"))
        Dim iRow As Long: iRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("1").Range("D4000").End(xlUp).Row
        For j = 5 To iRow
            b = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("C" & j)
            .Open "Get", "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?orgin=" & a & "&destination=" & b & "avoid=tolls", False
            .send
            lineS = Split(.responsetext, vbLf)
                For k = 25 To UBound(lineS)
                    If Trim(lineS(k)) = """distance"" :{" Then
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next k
            ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("e" & j) = lineS(k + 1)
            ThisWokrbook.Worksheets(1).Range("f" & j) = lineS(k + 5)
            Aplication.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
        Next j

    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Above is the excel that I would be using. C2 Would be the cell which I would be using to input the postcode, C5 to C3000, E would be distance output and F would be Time output.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `b` is not declared as string. `Dim a as String, b as String .... etc` is how it should be written.

Comment: Give me an example of input in C2 ..

Comment: You have misspelled `ThisWokrbook` and the `Aplication`. And I think you misspelled `origin=` in the URL too.

Comment: @YasserKhalil AB24 3DF this would be an example  - any post code for c5 and below to reference from. Also thank you, I did not see them mistakes.

Comment: I meant C5 and below .. But the postcode is in column D as you have attached.

Comment: Can you post sample of the JSON response as I have no API key?

Comment: @YasserKhalil Damn the post codes are meant to be D5 not C5

Answer (score 0):

There were typos in the URL. And you need to provide your GoogleAPIs key. 
This runs successfully on my Excel:

```
Option Explicit
Sub main()

Dim myURL, key As String
Dim iRow As Long
Dim WebSrvc  As New WebSrvc     ' create reference to class module
Dim result As String
Dim a, b As String
Dim j As Long
Dim pos1 As Long
Dim stxt As String

With ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
    ' Make sure, that your Google API key is in cell D2:
    key = .Range("D2").value

    ' Read Origin:
    a = CStr(.Range("C2"))

    iRow = .Range("D4000").End(xlUp).row
    For j = 5 To iRow
        ' Read Destination:
        b = .Range("D" & j)

        ' Query Google:
        myURL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=" & a & "&destination=" & b & "&avoid=tolls"
        myURL = myURL & "&key=" & key
        result = WebSrvc.OpenURL(myURL)

        ' Extract the (first) distance:
        pos1 = 1
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, "distance")
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, "value")
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, ": ")
        stxt = Mid(result, pos1 + 2, 100)
        .Range("D" & j).Offset(0, 1).value = val(stxt) / 1000#  ' convert meters to kilometers

        ' Extract the (first) time:
        pos1 = 1
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, "duration")
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, "value")
        pos1 = InStr(pos1, result, ": ")
        stxt = Mid(result, pos1 + 2, 100)
        .Range("D" & j).Offset(0, 2).value = val(stxt) / 60#    ' convert seconds to minutes

    Next
End With
End Sub
```

It uses the following class module named "WebSrvc":

```
'API-Declarations:
Private Declare Function InternetOpenA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
ByVal sAgent As String, ByVal lAccessType As Long, _
ByVal sProxyName As String, ByVal sProxyBypass As String, _
ByVal lFlags As Long) As Long

Private Declare Function InternetOpenUrlA Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
ByVal hOpen As Long, ByVal sUrl As String, _
ByVal sHeaders As String, ByVal lLength As Long, _
ByVal lFlags As Long, ByVal lContext As Long) As Long

Private Declare Sub InternetReadFile Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
ByVal hFile As Long, ByVal sBuffer As String, _
ByVal lNumBytesToRead As Long, lNumberOfBytesRead As Long)

Private Declare Sub InternetCloseHandle Lib "wininet.dll" ( _
ByVal hInet As Long)

'Enumeration for Internet:
Public Enum InternetOpenType
  IOTPreconfig = 0
  IOTDirect = 1
  IOTProxy = 3
End Enum

Public Function OpenURL( _
ByVal URL As String, _
Optional ByVal OpenType As InternetOpenType = IOTPreconfig _
) As String
  Const INET_RELOAD = &H80000000
  Dim hInet As Long
  Dim hURL As Long
  Dim Buffer As String * 2048
  Dim Bytes As Long
  OpenURL = "-1"

  'Open Inet-Connection:
  hInet = InternetOpenA( _
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:52.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/52.0", _
    OpenType, vbNullString, vbNullString, 0)
  If hInet = 0 Then
    Debuf.Print "Error in opening Internet Connection: " & Err.LastDllError
    Exit Function
  End If

  hURL = InternetOpenUrlA( _
    hInet, URL, vbNullString, 0, INET_RELOAD, 0)
  If hURL = 0 Then
    Debug.Print "Error in accessing URL: " & Err.LastDllError
    Exit Function
  End If

  ' Get the data:
  Do
    InternetReadFile hURL, Buffer, Len(Buffer), Bytes
    If Bytes = 0 Then Exit Do
    OpenURL = OpenURL & Left$(Buffer, Bytes)
  Loop

  ' Close Inet-Connection:
  InternetCloseHandle hURL
  InternetCloseHandle hInet
End Function
```